# Laravel 5.5. interface not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, interface

I have a different structure than Laravel original in a way that I have split my files to modules, and instead of using `app` I have everything nested under my `acme` folder.

I am getting an error that interface is not instantiable.

I have registered my `ContentServiceProvider` under `app.php` and here are the bindings:

```
    $this->app->bind('ContentService', ContentService::class);
    $this->app->bind(ItemServiceInterface::class, ContentService::class);
```

and here is the `provides()` method

```
public function provides()
{
    return [
        'ContentService',
        'ItemServiceInterface'
    ];
}
```

Namespaces should be fine since I have imported the classes directly instead of using a string for it. The interface itself is under a different namespace than service, but I suppose that isn't the issue?

Comment: on `provides` method, `'ItemServiceInterface'` should be `ItemServiceInterface::class` since you defined it as it is, doesnt it

Comment: I tried with that but no avail. Does it even need to be in the `provides()` method?

Comment: it should, when you defer the provider. otherwise, no.

Comment: Sorry for late response, write your answer, it is working. Thanks